# Multiple has and belongs to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model that has a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with two other models. For example, I have a `Message` model which has recipients. However, the recipients can be one of two different types of models. For example, `InternalContact`, and `ExternalContact`.

It is easy to set up relations where I can get either the Message's external contacts (`Message.first.external_contacts`) or its internal contacts (`Message.first.internal_contacts`). And then I can, in the same vein, easily add to this relationship array (`Message.first.external_contacts << ExternalContact.first`)

What I want is the ability to simply things and make this more efficiently by calling something like:

```
Message.first.recipients # an array of both external and internal contacts
Message.first.recipients << ExternalContact/InternalContact # (add either model)
```

Any direction is appreciated, I'm definitely stuck!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a separate recipient type table and then map messages only with recipients

```
Recipient          Recipient_type   Message       Message_recipient_map
----------         ---------------  -------       -------------------
id                 id               id            message_id  
recipient_type_id                                 recipient_id
```

Then you can have has_many_through relationship between message and recipient and can access all recipients of the message by calling message.recipients

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

With explicit has-and-belongs-to-many (aka `has_many through:`) relation model you'll have more control over the relation and can make one end of it polymorphic:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :message_recipients
  has_many :internal_recipients, through: :message_recipients, source: :recipient, source_type: "InternalContact"
end

class InternalContact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :message_recipients, as: :recipient
  has_many :messages, through: :message_recipients, inverse_of: :internal_recipients
end

class MessageRecipient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :recipient, polymorphic: true
end


msg = Message.create!
rec = InternalContact.create!
msg.internal_recipients << rec
msg.message_recipients.each{|mr|
  mr.recipient # here can be any model
}
```

Comment: I would call it a `has_many through:` association to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this if you want to avoid a polymorphic association is to use [Single Table Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance).

One major reason you would want to do this is to be able use a foreign key to ensure referential integrity which is not possible with polymorphism.

Since the types share a table you can also treat them like a homogeneous collection when it comes to ordering.

But single table inheritance is only really suited if the different types are very similar in nature and are interchangeable.

### Setting up STI

First create a `contacts` table where you will store all the different types.

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :type
      # and whatever columns you need 
      t.string :email
      # ...
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Pay attention to the `type` column. ActiveRecord will use this to store the class name of the subclasses. Then setup InternalContact and ExternalContact to inherit from the base `Contact` class:

```
class InternalContact < Contact
  # ...
end

class ExternalContact < Contact
  # ...
end
```

This lets you implement whatever logic you want (such as validations and callbacks) for each subtype.

### The associations

Start with the join table:

```
class CreateMessageRecipients < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :message_recipients do |t|
      t.belongs_to :message
      t.belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: { to_table: :contacts }
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Lets setup the associations with [`has_many through:`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and a join model instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many` which is very limited:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :message_recipients, foreign_key: :recipient_id
  has_many :messages, through: :message_recipients
end

class MessageRecipient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'Contact'
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :message_recipients
  has_many :recipients, through: :message_recipients
end
```